# Plugin could not be activated because it triggered a fatal error

Tags: wordpress, plugins, fatal-error

I am Using MyMail - Email Newsletter Plugin for WordPress

MyMail - Email Newsletter Plugin for WordPress :::: advanced Newsletter Plugin for WordPress. Create, Send and Track your Newsletter Campaigns
Version 1.6.6.1 | By revaxar

When I try to activate this plugin i got an Fatal Error (Plugin could not be activated because it triggered a fatal error.)

as in

............................................................

http://codecanyon.net/item/mymail-email-newsletter-plugin-for-wordpress/3078294/comments?page=24

Discussion on MyMail - Email Newsletter Plugin for WordPress

please open the wp-content/plugins/myMail/classes/templates.class.php

and remove this line around #657:

$this->copy_templates()

and try again

.......................................

i tried a lot like  PHP version related issue and all  but could't get any proper solution to resolve it

Plugin produces fatal error when attempting to activate .The big question I have now is this: What is the cause of this fatal error and how can I fix it? Can someone help me interpret so I can begin to see how I might overcome these fatal errors?

Comment: http://codecanyon.net/item/mymail-email-newsletter-plugin-for-wordpress/3078294/comments?page=24

Comment: it is a paid plugin and you have to get support form there, of if you are a coder then fix it by yourself.

Comment: yes it is paid plugin but the plugin which i have is not paid so i am not able to get support from there . so could you help me out how it fix it and yes i am coder but beginner so i don't get what exactly the issue is PHP version issue or another else ..

Comment: i got this plugin form nulled script provider                                                       
http://codecanyon.net/item/mymail-email-newsletter-plugin-for-wordpress/3078294                                



http://www.nulledlistings.com/?p=3815                              

http://linkzquickz.com/new/mymailemailnewsletter.zip                                      

http://bestnulledscripts.com/mymail-v1-6-6-1-email-newsletter-plugin-for-wordpress/                            

http://linkzquickz.com/new/mymail_v1.6.6.1.zip

Comment: Plugin produces fatal error when attempting to activate .The big question I have now is this: What is the cause of this fatal error and how can I fix it? Can someone help me interpret so I can begin to see how I might overcome these fatal errors?

Answer (score -1):

Please try to update your wordpress version and that plugin version usually this problem occurs when plugin was coded for previously developed wordpress. there may be the compatibility issue in wordpress and plugin.

Comment: i was tested this plugin with WP-3.9.2  and 4.0 ant the plugin version is 1.6.6.1         and i checked the requirement for this plugin at http://revaxarts-themes.com/?t=mymail/docs               

    WordPress 3.3+ (3.4+ recommended)
 and Plugin change log

Comment: Plugin produces fatal error when attempting to activate .The big question I have now is this: What is the cause of this fatal error and how can I fix it? Can someone help me interpret so I can begin to see how I might overcome these fatal errors?